# This Variable is not being set to R

Tags: macos, sh

I want to be able to make `jot = r`.

```
#!/bin/sh
jot -r 1 1 1000=R
echo $R
```

I just can't figure out what is the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
R=$(jot -r 1 1 1000)
echo "$R"
```